# How do I get rid of multiple DNS host records that have the same IP addresses?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a DNS server that has multiple host records that share IP addresses. I have scavenged the server and it didn't work. Is there an automated process that would be able to delete these host records no longer in use?

Thanks!!

Comment: What type of DNS server?  Bind, Microsoft?

Comment: Microsoft Server

Answer (score 2):

Again assuming MS DNS, scavenging doesn't wipe out duplicate entries on its own.  Manual scavenging only looks for expired entries according to the [Aging and Scavenging Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961420.aspx) already established.

To overly simplify, from the creation date, a DNS record must get through its no-refresh interval, then pass its refresh interval (without being refreshed) before scavenging can remove the record.

Lacking a better solution at this point and the time to dig into it just now... I generally just end up deleting a pile of duplicates, and letting the clients renegotiate things.

Comment: I wish someone had a better solution, however.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is Microsoft DNS, were these records created manually? If so, scavenging won't work. scavenging only works for dynamically created records.

Comment: These records were NOT created manually. It appears as if they were created from DHCP addresses. I checked the DHCP settings and they are correct now. I don't think they were set to release the IP address after leasing them.